# extracting labels of data in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When I move the mouse pointer over data in a pivot table it displays what are the row and column labels (names of pivot items).

How can I extract them so I can later use them in a code (when I want to refer to a specific value).

What is more can i get the column and row number of the data?

am

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. Read up on [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on here. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25666797/edit) your question and give all the necessary details.  HINT: `PivotField.LabelRange` Property and `PivotItem.LabelRange` are worth looking at.

Comment: ok, got it... the thing i needed was Sheet(n).Range(n).PivotCell.Row[or Column]Items.Item(n)
sorry for the fuss

Comment: No hassle, you could post an answer with what worked for you and accept it, it will  help other users (and you'll get a little rep for it too!)

Answer (score 0):

So, as for now the only way I know how to do it is to use:

```
Sheet(n).Range(n).PivotCell.Row[or Column]Items.Item(n)
```

Possibly not the best way, yet it works.